# When to use exit() over return?

Tags: c++, c, return, exit

I was wondering when should I use `exit()` function over `return` statement. I can end the program with either of the following statements:

```
exit(0);

  or

return;
```

Which one should I use and when?
Is there any advantage of using `exit()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two are very different in nature.

- `exit()` is used when you want to terminate program immediately. If a call to `exit()`  is encountered from *any* part of the application, the application finishes execution.
- `return` is used to *return* the program execution control to the *caller* function. In case of `main()` only, `return` finishes the execution.

---

EDIT:

To clarify about the case when used in `main()`, quoting directly from the `C11` standard, chapter §5.1.2.2.3, *Program termination*,

> If the `return` type of the `main()` function is a type compatible with `int`, a `return` from the initial call to the `main()` function is ***equivalent*** to calling the `exit()` function with the value returned by the `main()` function as its argument;<sup>11)</sup> reaching the `}` that terminates the
>   `main()` function returns a value of `0`. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the termination status returned to the host environment is  unspecified.

So, basically, either

- `return 0;`
- `exit(0);`

will behave as same in the context of `main()`.

Comment: so in main function will both work the same?

Comment: @SouravKanta updated my answer. Check it now.